# How can I translate my projection matrix in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, perspective, orthographic

I have a perspective camera.

When I do camera.projectionMatrix.makeTranslate nothing happens and my models stays still.

I also call update projection matrix and matrix world after doing the translation.

Is there a way i can move the model by changing projection and not needing to set the camera position?

Comment: Post the code in your question, don't link to it.

Comment: You’re right. See my edits please.